# How to parse an iCal Rss node

Tags: xpath, icalendar

Can someone help me with a line of code to access an iCal node from an RSS feed?

Specifically i want to access the xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name node.

My parent node is 'item', so the path is:

item/xCal:x-calconnect-venue/xCal:adr/xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name

How can i use parent.SelectChildNode() to access the value of that node?

Many thanks

b

Comment: And `SelectChildNode()` is part of what language? Please include some code as context and to show what you've been trying.

Comment: Good point Tomalak, its from asp.net C#

Comment: To my knowledge there is no `SelectChildNode()` function in the entire .NET framework. To Bing's knowledge neither: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=SelectChildNode&ac=3 So - what are you working with?

Comment: Forgive me Tomalak, that was a typo on my part the actual  method is called SelectSingleNode() so:

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
string s = node.SelectSingleNode("//@x-calconnect-venue-name").InnerText; 
}

Comment: Have you noticed that you can edit your own questions? Much better than cramming additions into comments. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the RSS item contents is something like this (irrelevant nodes omitted)

```
<item>
  <xCal:adr>
    <xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name>venue name</xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name>
  </xCal:adr>
</item>
```

Then you could do

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.xmlDoc);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xCal", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xcal");
// possibly add the RSS namespace as well?

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item"); 
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) { 
  XmlNode venue = node.SelectSingleNode(".//xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name", nsmgr);
  // watch out, there might not be a select result!
  if (venue != null) {
    string s = venue.InnerText;
    // ...
  }
}
```

or directly

```
string xpath = "rss/channel/item//xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name";
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr); 
foreach (XmlNode venue in nodes) { 
  string s = venue.InnerText;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Just to follow up, thanks again Tomalak this worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user: Thanks for the follow-up, glad that it worked. P.S.: An up-vote and an accept for this answer would be very much appreciated on my end. ;-)